# PHP regular expression to allow alphanumerics plus hyphens and periods

Tags: php, regex

I really don't understand regular expressions and was wondering what the following regular expressions do. I want my address and name to accept `.`, `-` and alphanumerics.

Will this work or is there need for improvement? Plus if someone can break down the regular expressions `'/^[A-Z0-9 \'.-]{1,255}$/i'` so I can understand every part better.

Here is the php code.

```
if (preg_match ('/^[A-Z0-9 \'.-]{1,255}$/i', $_POST['address'])) {
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, htmlentities($_POST['address']));
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">Please enter your address!</p>';
}

if (preg_match ('/^[A-Z0-9 \'.-]{1,255}$/i', $_POST['name'])) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, htmlentities($_POST['name']));
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">Please enter your name!</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern basically allowes any combination (between 1 and 255 characters) of the following: A-Z, 0-9, space, \, ', .

Decide for yourself if this is good enough.

As for your pattern:

```
/^[A-Z0-9 \'.-]{1,255}$/i
```

The i at the end means it isnt case sensitive

```
/^[A-Z0-9 \'.-]{1,255}$/
```

The slashes denote the beginning and the end of the pattern

```
^[A-Z0-9 \'.-]{1,255}$
```

The ^ is the beginning and $ is the end of the string you look for

```
[A-Z0-9 \'.-]{1,255}
```

This allowes and combination of the characters between the brackets with 1 to 255 repetitions

Answer (score 3):

`/`: Regex delimiter

`^`: Anchor the match at the start of the string

`[A-Z0-9 \'.-]`: Match a letter (A-Z, no accented characters), a number, a space, an apostrophe, a dot or a dash

`{1,255}`: between 1 and 255 times.

`$`: Anchor the match at the end of the string. Together with `^`, this ensures that the entire string must match, and not just a substring.

`/`: Regex delimiter

`i`: Make the regex case-insensitive